# Secure way to store database connection string in heroku

Tags: mongodb, heroku, database

I have an open source project on github, and I want to know a way to store my database's connection string without sharing it within the code. 
Maybe uploading a file that is not on git, with the credentials. Is it possible on Heroku? If not, how do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) are for. Set one, and it will be available to your app as an environment variable.  It lives outside your code base, as you (rightfully) want.